# Constraints and Stack View in iOS

Tags: ios, stack, constraints

I have noticed that though a stack may have proper constraints set (all blue lines), but the views inside the stack have incomplete constraints indicated by red lines. Does it matter? Do I need to ignore the individual constraints and focus only on stack constraints?

Comment: You should always try to resolve issues in your storyboards. I don't think your build will even succeed if you have errors raised in a storyboard file. It would appear that you have conflicting or missing constraints on the arranged subviews. Sometimes simply changing the `.alignment` and `.distribution` properties of the stack view can resolve the constraints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by experimenting, I have found that we need to resolve all constraint issues, be it of the stack view or any view inside the stack.